# Getting error creating hive table using delta table (with parquet format underneath)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet, delta-lake

I am getting one weird output when I am trying to create a hive table on top of delta

- Spark : 2.4.7
- Delta :.0.6.1

```java
import java.io.File    
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}    
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, SQLContext}
import io.delta.tables._    
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.symlinkFormatManifest.fileSystemCheck.enabled", false)

val df_1 = "select col1,col2 from table1"    
val df_2 = spark.sql(sqlText=df_1)

df_2.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("gs://<path>")

val deltaTable1 = DeltaTable.forPath("gs://<path>")

deltaTable1.generate("symlink_format_manifest")
```

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE deltahivetable(col1 decimal(18,0),col2 string)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'   
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'    OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'   
LOCATION 'gs://path/_symlink_format_manifest/'    
TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")
```

But getting , all the column value as null only and the count in the new table is very less also.

Any idea?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question without YELLING AT US.